# css class is not working in mvc4 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view page and in which i applied a Jquery like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hdrname = $('#headername').text();
    alert(hdrname);

    if (hdrname == "Pending Assignment") {
        $('#lst1').addClass('highlight1');
        alert("hcsgiahf");
        $('#tab2').removeClass('highlight1');
    }
    else if (hdrname == "Assigned With L1 Support") {
        alert($('#tab1').text());
        alert("hello");
        $('#tab1').removeClass('highlight1');
        $("#tab2").addClass("highlight1");
    }

    //To get No of call start

});
//To get No of call end
```

But when i am running my page css class highlight1 is not applied on the specified id, can any1 help me why it happens..

Comment: Chances are the if conditions fail if the class isn't added

Comment: show you html as well

Comment: Are you getting `alerts`?

Comment: Run $('#tab1').removeClass('highlight1'); in the Chrome Dev tools console. Does it work then?

Comment: first trim your text like this  var hdrname = $.trim($('#headername').text())

Comment: check $('#lst1') or $('#tab1')

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if (hdrname == "Pending Assignment") {
    $('#tab1').addClass('highlight1');// i think you are wrong here
    alert("hcsgiahf");
    $('#tab2').removeClass('highlight1');
}
else if (hdrname == "Assigned With L1 Support") {
    alert($('#tab1').text());
    alert("hello");
    $('#tab1').removeClass('highlight1');
    $("#tab2").addClass("highlight1");
}
```

[**Your code works here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a37y5/)